# using paper.js without canvas and paperscript

Tags: javascript, 2d

I hope not pose an already answered question, but I could not find something helpful anywhere. I am evaluating javascript libraries for 2d vector graphics and animation. On my way i found paper.js but no way to use it with type="text/javascript", without canvas and so on. In the paper.js FAQ about this point [here](http://paperjs.org/about/faq/#use-without-paperscript) i could find out that it might work, but for now i could not get it to work.

If anybody has any experience with this, it would be nice to let me know about this.

Comment: after some time of looking around i found annoying solution. Adding a new Script-Tag to head, just before the document is loaded. This script-tag needs to have a type of text/paperscript. Then it runs, but no debugging with firebug and so on. This is an mess! So if anybody got an idea, this would be great!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since version 0.2, using paper.js from pure JavaScript is easy and well documented.  One way to initialize is:

```js
var scope = new paper.PaperScope();
scope.setup(myCanvas);
```

Full documentation here: http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/

I'm not sure what you mean by "without canvas" though, paper.js does need a canvas object to operate.

Answer (score 4):

You can as of 0.11.4 (and perhaps before) create a canvas-less project in the same way as the accepted answer. More [here](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/634).

```
paper.setup(); // creates a new project
paper.setup([width, height]); // this also works for some width, height
// whatever vector calculations you now want to do.
```